# Conditionally adding Images to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I am trying to conditionally add images to my `UITableViewCell`. The user will add photos which in turn adds it to my `photoArray` array. The issue I am having is the images keep adding right after the other. I dont want to add a blank image to my array please. I will attach some code.

This is my `(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` method:

```
UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
self.photoImage = image;
[self.photoArray addObject:self.photoImage];
[self.tableView reloadData];
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Heres my `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListPrototypeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

XYZToDoItem *toDoItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Poiret One" size:18];
cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.itemName;

NSDictionary *dict = [self.tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"Time"];

if (indexPath.row<[self.photoArray count]) {
    UIImage *photo = [self.photoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = photo;
}

if (toDoItem.completed) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
return cell;
```

Comment: How do you trigger UIImagePickerController? By tapping on the row?

Comment: Sorry, i have a button that brings up the imagepicker.

Comment: do you have a button in each row of your table? Or you have one button for whole table?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say from your description but as far as I can understand from your source code - you have an array of ToDo item. Somehow you can assign a picture to some to-do items and you want to display it.

What you probably should do - is to make this picture (UIImage) part of your model. Add to your `XYZToDoItem`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *photo;
```

Then, when UIImagePickerController returns a picture - assign it to the corresponding `XYZToDoItem`

```
UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
self.photoImage = image; // Not sure why do you need that....
XYZToDoItem *currentItem = self.toDoItems[indexPath.row];
currentItem.photo = image;
[self.tableView reloadData];
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

But you will need to have selected row indexPath in this method. I'm not sure how do you present your `UIImagePickerController`

Comment: I know, its confusing. This is what I need to happen. When a user presses a button, the picture chosen is added to the cell. My problem is that the picture only adds the current `indexPath.row` from the array to the cell.

Comment: can you describe step by step how user add image to the cell? If you have several rows and one button "add picture", how your app knows to what cell do you want to add it?

Comment: I have 2 buttons on the top of the view. One camera picker button and one add to cell button. The user picks a photo and the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method is called. This adds it to my `photoArray` array. Now here's where it gets confusing. I only want the photo to display where in the cell the user wants it too, not one after another.

Comment: You probably better post some screenshots. I can't understand what you should have in result. Several photos in one cell?

Comment: It wont let me post an image. There is a tableview. The user chooses a photo to put in the cell. If the user does not want to add a photo, the next cell should be blank. My issue is all the cells are being populated with a photo from the array in sequential order. I need a way to choose which cell gets a photo.